# filter some data(row) in zend view

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have

1.Table:user(userId,userName,userGroup)

2.Model:userModel

3.usercontroller

there i a simple code:

## Controller:

```
class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{    
    public function getuser()
    {
      $userModel = new userModel();
      $this->view->usergroup = $userModel;
    }
}
```

---

## Model:

```
class Model_UserGroupModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
  public function getuser(
   {
 $select = $this->select();
 return $this->fetchAll($select);
   }
}
```

---

## view:

please tell me what code I must insert in view to only have user with specific row like user with group teacher also i use partialoop???

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($this->usergroup->toArray() as $userGroup) {
         echo $userGroup['row'];
}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

To filter rows based on a particular field like userGroup you need to do a query with where condition.

```
    $where = $this->getAdapter->quoteInto("userGroup = ?", 'teacher');
    $select = $this->select()->where($where);
```

So now you can get users for a particular user group.